# Running functions when a promise resolves

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using a promise to wait on a Facebook Graph response in the middle of a [Mocha test](http://mochajs.org). I'm wondering why [the `expect`](https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js) function is not actually checking that the data is `include`d in the response.

I see `resolve` in the console, suggesting the graph call worked and the promise resolved, but the test passes, even though the event does not include the random data in the `expect(data).to.include` statement. How can I get test the response when the promise resolves?

```
     var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
var eventFB1 = graph.get('132166232459578/posts',
  {limit: 1,
    access_token: 't0k3n'
  });

  if (typeof eventFB1 !== 'undefined') {
    resolve(eventFB1);
    console.log('resolve');
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
    console.log('reject');

  }
});

return promise.then(function(data) {
    expect(data).to.include( 'Event name: Testing London eveng 23498723rstni' );
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: while testing, you should probably fake the call to facebook.

Comment: I want to test that the post is actually being made to Facebook, all the wiring is working. It is a full acceptance test. I initially wanted to look at the post in the browser, but webdriver doesn't allow you to reject browser notifications, so I am checking it with the API now.